# Objective-c UIImage storage in MSMutableArray alternative, potential memory-leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, memory-leaks

I am building an app for iOS 5 using ARC and I seem to be having some memory issues. Basically its taking screen-shots of a portion of the display, placing the UIImage in an MSMutableArray and then piecing the screen-shots together for one big image. Now the problem is that after doing this a couple of times the OS closes the application due to high memory usage.

Here is the snippet that pieces the UIImage's together:

```
UIImage* finalImage = nil;
//join the screenshot images together
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(collage.width, collage.height));
{
    int hc = 0;
    for(UIImage *img in imageArr)
    {
        NSLog(@"drawing image at:: %i", hc);
        [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, hc)];
        hc+=img.size.height;
        img = nil;
    }

    //NSLog(@"creating finalImage");
    finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
//do something with the combined image
//remove all the objects
[imageArr removeAllObjects];
//reset class instance
[self setImageArr: [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
```

Are they any other alternatives that I could use so there isn't so much memory being used? Maybe storing a CGImageRef in the array? Are there any potential memory leaks with the above code?

Any tips, pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the imageArr is being cleared properly. There appears to be a memory issue somewhere else in the program.

Answer (score 1):

`[imageArr removeAllObjects];` will remove the objects from array.  No need to reset the array again with

```
 [self setImageArr: [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
```

By doing this you are allocating a NSMutableArray object and not releasing it.

Try by removing the line `[self setImageArr: [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you alloc and init setImageArr

```
if (setImageArr == nil){
setImageArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
else
{
[setImageArr removeAllObjects];
}
```

or use (if you want to init from an existing Array):

```
NSMutableArray *setImageArr = [[NSMtableArray]initWithArray:arrayOfImages];
```

Comment: The imageArr is a @synthesized instance variable so I am not sure I understand why you suggest setting another array to contain the image array.

Comment: I was saying to make sure you still alloc and init imageArr. You can init this array with another if you want to (a hypothetical array I called arrayOfImages

Answer (score 0):

Because you say it will have memory issue after `doing this a couple of times`. Then how about you use `NSAutoreleasePool` to force system release objects after your method, example below:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    UIImage* finalImage = nil;
    //join the screenshot images together
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(collage.width, collage.height));
    {
        int hc = 0;
        for(UIImage *img in imageArr)
        {
            NSLog(@"drawing image at:: %i", hc);
            [img drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, hc)];
            hc+=img.size.height;
            img = nil;
        }
        finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //do something with the combined image
    //remove all the objects
    [imageArr removeAllObjects];
    //reset class instance
    [self setImageArr: [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
}
```

And I also doubt there is any memory leak problem in your other codes.
Using ARC doesn't meaning without memory leak problem, maybe you store many useless objects in a global variable etc.

Maybe you should use Instruments to monitor the memory to figure out where does the memory go.

Comment: Hmm, autoreleasepool doesn't appear to be available with ARC.

Comment: @thiesdiggity Yes, it's replaced with `@autoreleasepool` in ARC, see my sample code.